# Problem to return a value from an AngularFireList

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not able to get an object when I try to look for it through one of its attributes in an AngularFireList. What do you suggest?

[Table Structure on FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kejm5.png)

Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Prestamo } from '../models/prestamo';
import { FirebaseDatabase } from 'angularfire2';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PrestamoService {

  prestamoLista: AngularFireList<any>;
  prestamoSeleccionado: Prestamo = new Prestamo();

  constructor(private firebase: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  obtenerPrestamos()
  {
    return this.prestamoLista = this.firebase.list('prestamos');
  }

  obtenerPrestamo(codigo: string)
  {
    return this.prestamoLista = this.firebase.list('prestamos', ref => ref.orderByChild('codigo').equalTo(codigo));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the `snapshotChanges` list from the service,

```
  obtenerPrestamos()
  {
    return this.firebase.list('prestamos').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

From component subscribe to the observable

```
this.yourService.obtenerPrestamos().subscribe((data) => {
   console.log(data)
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @SachilaRanawaka ! But my problem is on the method 
_obtenerPrestamo(codigo: string)_ , which it searchs through code atribute.